# Node Mongoose Seperate Indexes for Seperate Queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing

Can we create completely separate indexes for completely separate queries on the same collection?

I want an efficient query for users retrieving their activities using an index like so

```
index{ userDBID: 1 }
```

Example query

```
ActivityModel.find({ userDBID }).lean();
```

I want a separate efficient query for entire app statistics which gets activities also, but needs use a separate compound index like so

```
index{season: 1, matchID: 1}
```

Example queries

```
ActivityModel.find({ season, matchID }).lean()
ActivityModel.find({ season }).lean();
```

I am finding it hard to find a solid high-quality answer. I know hint() seems to be a solution, but I am sceptical about that one.

Daniel

Comment: Please post what your queries are. There is no way to determine if your indexes are useful are not without looking at the query definitions.

Comment: @prasad There is no need, but I'll add anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can.

You can just add:

```
schema.index({ userDBID: 1 });
schema.index({ season: 1, matchID: 1 });
```

right after your schema declaration, before saving the Model with `mongoose.model('Model', schema);`.

You will see (after a while) the new schema added in the DB. If you use an inspection tool like `MongoDB Compass` you'll even have a visual representation.

I am using this efficiently in a production app so I am certain of this (just today's usage):

http://prntscr.com/qj1n2o

Comment: How then do I use that index specifically when making a query?

Comment: The index is added and any query to the DB will use the index you don’t have to add any other action! :)

Comment: So you saying it will auto recognise I am searching using userDBID and auto use that index?